# Display list without bullets on a specific page

Tags: html, css, html-lists

This is my website:

http://goo.gl/qTjPb

In this page (only), I don't want to show bullets.

I tried to use internal css, but it did not work:

```
  <ul style="list-style:none">
```

External css did not work either:

```
  <ul class="test"> 

  .test{list-style:none;}
```

Could you help me to figure this out? Thank you.

Comment: [How do I write a good title?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title) & [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: post your code of the div it has to be done in.

Comment: PLease provide a snippet on jsfiddle.com

Comment: Bondye: thanks for your suggestion,  so could you give me an example about my title?  if you were me , what title you would put on? thank you :)

Comment: Something like `Display list without bullets on a specific page` just exactly what you want to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the class

```
<ul class="nobullets">
   ....
</ul>
```

then in css

```
ul.nobullets li {
  list-style: none;
}
```

or

```
ul.nobullets li {
  list-style: none !important;
}
```

this will guarantee the bullets are removed only in that UL - in that page

Comment: hi Pedro3M  I tried to use your way, but it does not work. http://goo.gl/qTjPb  could you help me to find out what's wrong? thank you

Comment: that have to work try putting list-style: none !important;

Comment: it works,  i use ul.nobullets li {
  list-style: none !important;
}     really thank you!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Line 38 of your style.css file has `#content #default li{margin-left:30px;list-style: disc;}` which overrides your inline `<ul style="list-style: none;">` rule.

Answer (score 0):

You must apply the list-style:none to the `<li>` not to the `<ul>`.